# Получение значение Y при перемещении с помощью анимации

Tags: java, android, анимация

У меня анимация перемещения написана в `xml` файле. Как получить переменную `Y`  в определенный момент времени, например, при нажатие на кнопку?
Вот код

```
 for (int aab = 0; aab < lines; aab++) {
     for (int aaa = 0; aaa < 75; aaa++) {
         anim[aab][aaa] = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytrans);
     }
 }


linLay[irand].addView(ntv[irand][xxx[irand]], lparam1);
ntv[irand][xxx[irand]].startAnimation(anim[irand][xxx[irand]]);
ntv[irand][xxx[irand]].setClickable(true);
ntv[irand][xxx[irand]].setId(irand * 100 + xxx[irand]);
```

Comment: А как вы анимируете?

Comment: покажите код, как вы запускаете анимацию.

Comment: вопрос поправил

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы используете **objectAnimator**, то `yourView.getY()`